# The "revisions" page (not to be confused with the "review" page)

Tags: support, editing

For the first time when someone edited my question I received a notification and I was forwarded to the [revision page](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/414670/revisions) at "math.stackexchange.com/posts/414670/revisions"

Can I access such a page for any other questions, which ones and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. When a post is edited, a link to the revisions page is added to it. Click on the "edited [timestamp]" link to get there. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/414563/4583) for an example.

Edit: I've edited this post to add an "edited" link here too.

Comment: ...and for unedited posts, or in general, just replace the number in `math.stackexchange.com/posts/414670/revisions` with the post number (which is the first number you'll see when you look at the URL produced by hovering over the "share" button).

Comment: @J.M.'s suggestion is _extremely helpful_ if you want to look at things that records in the history but does not produce an "edited" link. For example: history of when the question was closed/re-opened, when the post was locked, or when a question was given a bounty.